# Android : Horizontal Calendar wrong date is getting selected

Tags: java, android, kotlin

On picking a date in `horizontal calendar` its picking a wrong date.
For example I am selecting 17th june but its picking 18th june
Working fine on horizontal scrolling

```
horizontalCalendar = HorizontalCalendar.Builder(this, R.id.calendarView).startDate(startDate.time).endDate(endDate.time).datesNumberOnScreen(7).dayNameFormat("EEE").dayNumberFormat("dd").monthFormat("MMM").showDayName(true).showMonthName(false)

        .selectedDateBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext, R.drawable.sample_selected_background)).defaultSelectedDate(defaultDate.time).build()
```

Comment: share some related code what you tried...

Comment: horizontalCalendar = HorizontalCalendar.Builder(this, R.id.calendarView)
                .startDate(startDate.time)
                .endDate(endDate.time)
                .datesNumberOnScreen(7)
                .dayNameFormat("EEE")
                .dayNumberFormat("dd")
                .monthFormat("MMM")
                .showDayName(true)
                .showMonthName(false)
                .selectedDateBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext, R.drawable.sample_selected_background))
                .defaultSelectedDate(defaultDate.time)
                .build()

Comment: Another thing which i have just noticed datesNumberOnScreen(7) but its showing only 6 dates on the screen. When i changed it from 7 to 8 or 7 to 6 . Its jumping two position above.

Comment: then try to show 5 days like  `.datesNumberOnScreen(5)`

Comment: Its working with .datesNumberOnScreen(5) . As its scrolling the view to center. Thanks!!

Comment: HorizontalCalendar??

Comment: @EpicPandaForce sir - Is there anything wrong with the term horizontal calendar view??

Comment: I'm just not sure which specific library it is considering that is not built-in

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .datesNumberOnScreen(7) try using .datesNumberOnScreen(5) as the screen scroll to the centre.
This solution helped me. Thankyou Omi !

Answer (score 1):

Please check that the HorizontalCalendarView component is not a child of some UI-behavior-specific components, like SwipeRefreshLayout, as it was in my case.